# iOS Swift 3 Check each date is valid, before filtering array

Tags: arrays, swift, filter, option-type

```
let dateFormat = DateFormatter()
dateFormat.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

filtereditems = items.filter { item in return dateFormat.date(from: item.date)! >= Date()}
```

I have code above to filter items in my array, which are greater than or equal to todays date, which works fine.

However, I want to check the dateFormat.date(from: item.date)! is valid as if the date can not parse or is not in the correct format, my app crashes out.

I know about optionals, as below, but I'm not sure they fit together. e.g..

```
if let temp_date = dateFormat.date(from: item.date) as? Date {
     //valid
} else {
     //invalid
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you need only the conditional
binding, not the conditional cast with `as? Data`:

```
let filtereditems = items.filter { item in
    if let temp_date = dateFormat.date(from: item.date) {
        // valid date string: compare with current date
        return temp_date >= Date()
    } else {
        // invalid date string: skip
        return false
    }
}
```

Or – if you prefer – with `guard`:

```
let filtereditems = items.filter { item in
    guard let temp_date = dateFormat.date(from: item.date) else {
        // invalid date string: skip
        return false
    }
    // valid date string: compare with current date
    return temp_date >= Date()
}
```

Alternatively, use the nil-coalescing operator `??` to map
invalid strings to a date in the past:

```
let filtereditems = items.filter { item in
    return dateFormat.date(from: item.date) ?? Date.distantPast >= Date()
}
```

or with parameter shortcuts:

```
let filtereditems = items.filter {
    dateFormat.date(from: $0.date) ?? Date.distantPast >= Date()
}
```

*Remark:* A better approach might be to change the type of `date`
in your item class from `String` to `Date?`, and do the conversion
during initialization. That might save repeated string to date
conversions.